# Can kinetic energy be transferred between two objects even if they are not in contact?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, energy-conservation, conservation-laws, inertial-frames

This question is better explained with a thought experiment. It is inspired by [this answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/716090/339694), stating that the amount of work done depends on the inertial frame.

Consider a one-dimensional space with two spheres $1$ and $2$ of equal mass and a grenade $g$ directly in the middle between them. In a general case, the spheres have kinetic energy $E_1$ and $E_2$, though a restriction to non-relativistic velocities is imposed. The mass of the grenade shall be negligible such that its kinetic energy is zero, however it has internal energy stored $E_{g,i}$ which will be released on the spheres upon detonation. Thus, the system has an initial state $i$ and a final state $f$, before and after detonation of the grenade, respectively. The grenade releases the entirety of its internal energy at the detonation $E_{g,f} = 0$.

Compare the following two inertial frames:

1. All objects are initially at rest $v_{1,i} = v_{2,i} = v_{g,i} = 0$, thus $E_{1,i} = E_{2,i} = 0$. After detonation and according to
   symmetry, both spheres receive an equal amount of energy from the
   grenade $E_{1,f} = E_{2,f} = E_{g,i}/2$ and accordingly $v_{1,f} =
   -v_{2,f}$.
2. All objects move with a constant velocity $v_{1,i} = v_{2,i} = v_{g,i} = \tilde{v}$. For simplicity's sake, the energy released by the grenade is just the right amount, such that $v_{2,f} = 0$ and $E_{2,f} = 0$. This is the case precisely when $E_{1,i} = E_{2,i} = E_{g,i}/2$. Now, what is the energy of the other sphere after detonation $E_{1,f}$? It is the only object in the final state of this system that carries energy. Thus, by conservation of energy $E_{1,f} = E_{1,i} + E_{2,i} + E_{g,i} = 2E_{g,i}$.

For me this result is problematic. In the second case, sphere $1$ seems to consume both the initial kinetic energy from sphere $2$ and the full internal energy of the grenade, though the spheres appear to receive equal and opposing forces from the explosion in the rest frame of case one.

Plugging in some numbers, if the grenade contains 4J of energy, then in case one each of the spheres receives 2J from the explosion, while in case two 6J of work were done on sphere $1$ since it ends up with 8J of kinetic energy.

I think there is something fundamentally wrong about the way I imagine energy transfer. Can you spot a mistake or help me out?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't really see how the set up really corresponds to your question, transfer of energy can happen contactlessly all the time.Just take the "collision" of two charged particles, all the interaction is done through the fields. With the way the below answer and comments go it seems more like you are grappling with the frame dependence of certain quantities.

Comment: The set up is supposed to be different from the collision of charged particles because sphere $1$ gains energy which seems to originate from sphere $2$ even though they are spatially well separated and the energy of the grenade can't explain the difference (though perhaps the grenade's energy it is dependent on the inertial frame, which I still don't fully understand)

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong. As you said, the work and kinetic energy are not frame invariant.

Intuitively, that means: 1 object with a given velocity can cause more damage than 2 objects with half that velocity. Or exagerating the effect: being blasted with several bullets being throwned at us from several people by hand is less dangerous than one bullet from a gun.

Comment: The non-linearity of kinetic energy perfectly explains your examples and this may also be the key to my question as well but I can't see the link (yet). In my question an inconsistency arises when comparing two different inertial frames. How can a grenade that contains 4J of internal energy perform 6J of work and how does this compare to your bullet example?

Comment: Because energy is frame dependent, it is not possible to say that a granade has $4J$ for all frames. Suppose that the result of the explosion is two parts, of small mass but high velocity, being absorved by the objects. The kinetic energy of the granade fragments after explosion depends on the frame.

Comment: Isn't this extremely counter intuitive? The energy content of a fuel would depend on its velocity, i.e. a battery on a moving train would contain a different energy than an identical one at the train station, according to an observer at the station.

Comment: Since the kinetic energy rises quadratically, the difference in kinetic energy between the two parts rises non-linearly with $\tilde{v}$ but the difference in velocity to the spheres stays the same, no matter the frame of reference. This would explain why the energy is no longer evenly distributed!

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that you have understood the solution. However the results sounds weird to you. I agree. Here are some more weird facts about work and kinetic energy. Enjoy.

- Kinetic energy depends on frame of reference. A stationary block on ground has zero kinetic energy. Yet it has kinetic energy when observed from a moving frame.
- Change in kinetic energy depends on frame. If an object accelerates from 0 to v, change in kinetic energy is increase of $\frac{1}{2}mv^{2}$. From another frame, the particle has accelerated from v to 2v. Change in kinetic energy is increase of $\frac{3}{2}mv^{2}$. From yet another frame, the particle has accelerated from -v to 0. So now change is a decrease of $\frac{1}{2}mv^{2}$. From yet another frame it has accelerated from -v/2 to +v/2. Kinetic energy is constant. I have only considered motion along a single axis till now!
- Work depends on frame. A block is slips on ground and stops due to friction. Work done by friction on block is negative when observed from ground. Yet the work is zero from block's frame. This work can be made positive from yet another frame! (try moving along block - but faster!)
- Yet $\Sigma Work = \Delta KE$ is valid from all inertial frames! Please note that both LHS and RHS are different from different frames.

Potential energy does not take part in all this drama.

The example that you have taken up involves both kinetic and potential energy (of grenade). All the 'counter intuitive' part can be blamed on  weird behavior of kinetic energy on  frame change.